# How to run code in an iOS app from a UI test in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to run code in the app from a UI test in Xcode 7? This is possible with application tests (since the tests run in the app), but there doesn't appear to be a simple way with UI tests.

Has anyone figured out a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward way to run code in the app you are executing your app from UI tests is to supply [launchArguments via XCUIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuiapplication/1500477-launcharguments).

**ui test code**

```
import XCTest

class UITestUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments += ["-anargument", "false","-anotherargument","true"]
        app.launch()
    }

}
```

**app code**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    print("All arguments: \(NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments)\n\n")
    print("anargument: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("anargument"))")
    print("anotherargument: \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("anotherargument"))")
    return true
}
```

**app output when launched from ui test:**

```
All arguments: ["/...../AnApp.app/UITest", "-anargument", "false", "-anotherargument", "true"]

anargument: false
anotherargument: true
```

Answer (score 1):

UI Testing runs in a separate process from your app. There is currently, as of Xcode 7.1.1, no way to interact directly with the production app's code from the framework.

Every interaction must route through accessibility. This means that you *could* wire up a button that executed code in your app, then have the tests call that button. This is obviously not scalable and I would recommend against it.

Maybe there is another way to achieve your goals? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There are a couple things I'm trying to accomplish. For example, I want tests to be data driven, so they need to be able to access the app's data. I also want to take shortcuts (I have a huge number of existing KIF tests that I'd like to switch over--they take hours to run).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of passing an environment variable to the app when testing which launches an embedded HTTP server. Then I can communicate with the app through the server. Crazy, right? And yet, I can't believe nobody has done this yet.

My biggest concern with this approach is that the embedded server will be in the production app. I'm not sure if that is a problem, or if there's a simple way to only include it when running UI tests.

Comment: Did you end up doing that? I'm considering it too

Comment: Yes, I've used this technique in a few projects. I have the server included only in Debug builds of the app.

Comment: I also went that route too. Started a node app outside of the test/actual apps.